# reading remote PC disk capacities via .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, application-design

I'm planning on writing a small program that uses the .NET framework to read disk capacities on remote Windows PCs.

I normally write in C#, so I'd like to stick with this. A number of us in our department need access to this program.

Should I write this as:

- a desktop app
- an MMC snap-in
- an ASP.NET application with a service?

Any suggestions? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A different idea, what about a PowerShell cmdlet with WMI?

Answer (score 1):

A service with WCF comes into my mind. Thus, a central application could query the service on each remote windows PC to get the information.

If these PC's already publish their disc capacities in some form (eg. via windows shares or something else), you could omit the service part and directly query the machines.

Answer (score 0):

WMI already publishes this information. So all you need is a client. Depending on the needs of your users, it could be a WinForms app, an MMC SnapIn, a console app, etc etc.